# Creating a hibernate-mapping XML for my multi-table select SQL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to understand how to create a mapping XML for a single select that retrieves various fields from various tables.

See SQL below (to make it simple, I'll just retrieve all the fields in each of the tables)

```
SELeCT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
from
    table1 a,
    table2 b,
    table3 c,
    table4 d
where
    a.id = b.id
    and a.id = c.id (+)
    and a.code = d.code (+)
    and a.id = 34
```

Here's the table definitions.

My main table is table1 and it has a 1-to-1 relationship with table2. table1 may or may not have a corresponding record in table3 and table4. the id columns in tables 1, 2 and 4 have the same value. (e.g. if table1.id = 34 and if table1 has a record in table3 and4, then table3.id and table4.id = 34)

```
table1 (
    id int,
    code varchar2(255)
)

table2 (
    id int,
    some_column1 varchar2(255)
    some_column2 varchar2(255)
)

table3 (
    code varchar2(255),
    description varchar(512)
)

table3 (
    id int,
    url varchar(1024)
)
```

I've been reading the HQL primer  and basic o/R on the jboss.org site but it doesn't really tell me much in regards on how to create an hibernate mapping XML for my SQL above.

thank you! :)

Comment: More adapt would be ER diagram. But I will try to answer that.

Comment: no ER tool here :/ but I added more info if that would help. I understand the added info is very simple but I hope you get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write a valid [XML mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html) for Hibernate is [to read this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html).

The few things that reader show focus are:

- XML class mapping
- Type of relation

As in your example we have four tables. The should be connected somehow.

So first step would be to create a POJO classes for all tables, and XML mapping for simple properties.

The model should look like

```
class A {
  int id; 
  String code;
  B b
  C c;
  D d;
} 

class B {
  int id;
}

class C {
  int id;
}

class D {
  String code;
}
```

The mapping

join between A and B

`<one-to-one name="b"  class="B">`

Then we map table C (a.id = b.id(+))

`<many-to-one name="c" class="C"/>`

And we map table D (a.code = c.code(+))

`<many-to-one name="d" class="D" column="CODE"/>`